# Martingale Transform counterexample

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am studying discrete time martingale theory and came across the classical "You can't beat the system" theorem: given a martingale $M$ and a previsible process $C=(C_n)_{ n \ge 1}$ such that $C_n$ is limited for every $n$ the martingale transform $C \bullet M $ is a martingale. My question is: can we find a martingale $M$ and $C$ previsible but not limited such that the martingale transform is no longer a martingale?

I have been looking for a similar topic but only found discussions in continuous time which I could not understand (I have no knowledge yet of stochastic continuous time calculus)...
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "limited"? Bounded?

Comment: Yes! (sorry for bad English)

Comment: Take $C_n=M_{n-1}$, then $C$ is integrable but $C\bullet M $ is a martingale if and only if $M$ is square integrable.

Answer (score 0):

You are betting on fair independent coin flips. You must decide your bet $C_{n+1}$ for time $n+1$ at time $n$, i.e. you don't get to view the coin flip before deciding whether you chose heads or tails. Then your profit is given by $X = C \cdot M$.

Consider the strategy of betting a random huge amount each time, e.g. taking $C_n \notin L^1$, then $X_n \notin L^1$ and is thus $X$ is not a martingale because $|X_1|=|C_1| \notin L^1$, i.e. you either won or lost the huge amount you staked.

Comment: That is exactly my problem: if i have a bonded C i can easily say that $(C\bullet M)_n$ is $L^1$ without "knowing" the values of $M_n $, but i can't understand how to prove that $X_n$ is not $L^1$ without being more "explicit" about it...If we look at the coin tossing example you made, for example, how can we prove that $X_1$ is not $L^1$ without knowing joint laws?

Comment: Couldn't it just happen that e.g. the product of $C_1$ and $M_1-M_0$ is a.s. 0?Isn't $a$ $ priori$  |X1|=|C1| only on a subset of $ \{ C_1 \neq 0 \} $ ? I think your answer is very plausible, but i would find it very helpful if i could see some "calculations"...Thank you very much!

Comment: By definition $X_1 = C_1(M_1-M_0)$.  The setup I have implicitly assumed is a standard "coin toss" space, where $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n F_i$ where the $F_i$ are IID coin flips ($1/2$ probability of $+1$, and $1/2$ probability of $-1$). Then $M_1-M_0 = F_1$ is the result of one of the flips. Hence $X_1 = C_1(M_1-M_0)=C_1F_1$ and $|X_1| = |C_1||F_1| = |C_1| |\pm 1| = |C_1|$. This analysis does rely on the structure of the coin toss space. If I had chosen $M_n = 0$ to be the zero martingale, clearly I would have $X_n = 0$ for all $n$ and indeed $C \cdot M = 0$ regardless of $C$.